# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’

Tags: r, shiny, tmap

I am getting the error below when I am trying to run my shiny app which used to work properly; I did not get this error using the old version of my R/Rstudio. Currently, I am using Version 1.1.463 of Rstudio, and R version 4.0.3.
Thanks,
Nader

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘raster’

Comment: Try running `install.packages("raster")` on the machine that's hosting your shiny app. It sounds like that required package dependency is missing.

Comment: Thanks; I successfully installed "ratser" but still getting the same error.

Comment: It gives the exact same error? That seems odd. If after you've installed `raster`, can you run `library(raster)` to make sure it loads? How did you load `tmap` initially?

Comment: Thanks MrFlick; please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with installing the ratser. When the question below prompted during the installation, I answered no instead of yes, and this solved the issue. Thanks.

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)